# How can I make a dictionary from a pandas data frame where the values are data types?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, types

I have a dataframe called "Lookup" that looks something like this:

```
   | Variable | Type
0  | Var1     | object
1  | Var2     | np.uint16
```

I want to use this to create a dictionary to import a large csv to keep the memory size low.

The large csv is too large to use the low_memory=False option of pd.read_csv.

I could change the data type afterwards or manually type out all of the variables but I have 200+ variables and don't want to write the dictionary out explicitly.

I have used the following code

```
Lookup= Lookup.set_index('Variable')
dic = Lookup.to_dict('dict')
```

and

```
dic = dict(zip(Lookup['Variable'].tolist(), Lookup['Type'].tolist()))
```

but both end up with the same problem of putting 'Type' inside quotes in the dictionary, e.g. "np.uint16" rather than np.uint16

This means that when I run the read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", nrows=100, dtype=dic)
```

I get the error "TypeError: data type "np.uint16" not understood"

How can I make a dictionary containing the variable and the data type from the pandas data frame that can then be used inside of the read_csv statement without erroring?

N.B. The "input.csv" is 100M+ rows long and 250+ columns wide so the aim of all of this is to make the pandas dataframe take up as little memory as possible while still maintaining precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it that I can think of.

One is to use a `dict` mapping, as follows:

```
dtype_mapping = {'np.uint8': np.uint8,
                 'np.uint16': np.uint16,
                 ...all your dtypes here...
                 'object': 'np.object'}

dtypes = [dtype_mapping[dtype] for dtype in Lookup['Type']]

dic = dict(zip(Lookup['Variable'].tolist(), dtypes)
```

...and then you continue from there.

The second (that needs less typing, but that I find slightly dodgy, because it allows arbitrary code execution), is evaluation:

```
dtypes = [eval(dtype) for dtype in Lookup['Type']]

dic = dict(zip(Lookup['Variable'].tolist(), dtypes))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Your first answer has done the job :-)

Comment: @RichardKapustynskyj if my answer helped you, accept it please!

Answer (score 2):

If this is your file `test.csv`

```
Name1;Number1;Number2;Name2
a;2;3.0;b
```

then you can define a type series

```
types = pd.Series(data=['object', 'float', 'float', 'object'], index=['Name1', 'Number1', 'Number2', 'Name2'])
types = types.apply(eval)
```

and use this to read in your data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';', dtype=types.to_dict())
```